Archiving past sprints question in DevOps
In Microsoft DevOps, we have a few older sprints that we want to archive. (e.g. as they're older sprints, they are no longer needed and we want to archive them). I wonder what is the best way to archive sprints?
I found the following link from Microsoft, which has a section named "Archive past sprints": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/end-sprint-activities?view=azure-devops
It mentions I could move them to the Previous Sprints node, but I can't find this node in my DevOps.
